# Redirect to https but only specific domains/subdomains and specific url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all traffic from  HTTP to HTTPS, but only if a specific url is different from /oldsite (but only in subdomains sub1 and sub2)

for example:

```
http://example.com/any/thing --> redirects to --> https://example.com/any/thing

http://sub1.example.com/any/thing --> redirects to --> https://sub1.example.com/any/thing
```

but

```
http://example.com/oldsite/any/thing
```

and

```
http://sub1.example.com/oldsite/any/thing -> do not cause this redirect
```

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:(sub1|sub2)\.)?example\.com 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/oldsite [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thank you.

UPDATE: Also tested last two lines as:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/oldsite [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301, NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have your rule when `HTTPS` is off and use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/oldsite [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you... but didn't worked... it still redirects to HTTPS... any ideas?
I just accesed to http://example.com/oldsite/a/b... and it redirects me to HTTPS version

Comment: Make sure this is first rule in your .htaccess and you completely clear your browser cache or test from command line `curl` or `wget`